# App Build successful, upload shows successful but not showing up on app store connect/ my app/ activity tab?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

No major errors are shown while building and uploading the app. But builds not showing up on the activity tab on my app section.
I've tried increasing the build number and reuploading the build 8 times over last month.
Tried contacting Apple, they say build processing failed on their side and we will receive an automated mail regarding the error. But there is no such mail received to me. When I try to reupload the older build it shows build already exists error. I'm clueless about what's happening. Kindly assist me on this issue.

Comment: did you manage to solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, no errors in XCode, no problem uploading my app, no emails from Apple that there is an issue, nada. Send numerous requests to Apple - no reply.

Called them and was told WebViews were the issue, despite that neither XCode nor upload reported it.

The worst thing is, as I was told, Apple WILL NOT NOTIFY YOU about webviews being an issue at all because they send out an email couple of years ago and you should have read it!